# Get Token From Api Dynamically To Access Content

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, access-token, es6-promise, fetch-api

I need to have the token to access the content like the announcement in my code. But what i do is to copy the token generated from loginUser() and paste it inside the getAnnouncement() under the fetch. I wrote Authorization : 'Bearer esuigiugeguigiguigi' <--- this is the token. The problem with this is that i need to copy and paste again the token every time it expires.

```
function loginUser(){

fetch('http://sample_website.com/api/auth/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({
        email: document.getElementById("email").value,
        password: document.getElementById("password").value
    })
})
.then(data => data.json() )
.then(data =>  { 

    if(data.response){
        redirect: window.location.replace("../Sample/Home.html") 
    } else{
        alert("Invalid Email or Password");
    }
}) 
.catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
})
```

}

```
function getAnnouncement(){

fetch('http://sample_website.com/api/announcements', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization : 'Bearer esuigiugeguigiguigi'},      
})
.then(data => data.json())
.then(data => { console.log(data)

        const output = document.getElementById("display");
        output.innerHTML = `<ul>
                        <li><h2>${data.data.data[0].title}</h2></li>
                        <li>${data.data.data[0].body}</li>
                        <li>Created: ${data.data.data[0].created_at}</li> 
                        </ul>`;

})
.catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
})
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Usually the response from an API call to get the token will hold:

- the token
- the duration of the toke
- a link to refresh the token

One basic way of dealing with this is to keep the token data in localStorage or in memory or something (you can decide for yourself), and then just use it on any request that needs authorization.

It is possible that the API in question gives a specific error in case a token has expired. You can then catch it, use the link to refresh the token to get a new one, and repeat the request.

As there is not much info about the API in hand, or what you're doing and what (if any) framework you are using, this it the best answer I can provide at the moment. There are a lot of libraries out there handling this stuff already, so you might want to look into existing solutions as well.